# How to create Group in Salesforce using apex from standard user

Tags: apex, permissions

Is it possible to create a group from standard user in apex without user having Customize Application permission

Answer (score 1):

Able to create Group in Without Sharing class

Answer (score 0):

It might not possible to create Group using standard user.

```
Group objGroup = new Group(Name = 'TestGroup1', Type='Regular');
insert objGroup;
```

The above code works for System Administrator profile, but it does not work for Standard User.